# Let regex both accept Swedish characters and work on my website

Tags: php, regex

I have the following function that allows me to highlight a word.

```
function highlight($text, $word) {
    preg_match_all('~\w+~', $word, $m);
    if(!$m) return $text;
    $re = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $m[0]) . ')\\b~i';
    return preg_replace($re, '<mark>$0</mark>', $text);
}
```

The problem is that it dosen't highlight Swedish characters, like Åå, Ää, and Öö. But if I remove both of the `~` from the regex, it will accept the Swedish characters on [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xbPir1YJHQzwMILW).

But when I try to run it through my website, I'll get this error message: `Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in ... on line 56`, which is this line: `preg_match_all('\w+', $word, $m);`.

How can I make it highlight Swedish characters and also work on my website with it?

Comment: Use `u` modifier to make patterns Unicode-aware and make the PCRE engine treat input strings as Unicode strings.

Comment: Thank you. However, neither `~\w+~u` or `/^[\w]+$/u` works. It dosen't highlight any word that contains the Swedish characters.

Comment: https://eval.in/897698

Comment: Ahaa! The regex on line 5 in my code above, was required `u` too! It's working now :) Many thanks!